# Why is my CPU usage 100% while i am not running anything on my computer?

Tags: cpu

I have noticed this issue today when i started my computer. My fan is making a lot of noise as if its overworking and my CPU usage is 100%. Though i am not running any other application but Google Chrome. Now, i went to taskmanager and checked out the process that's taking much of my CPU and found this "system" thing which is almost consuming 80% of my CPU. Now, when i clicked on the file location it turns out to be located in the Windows->System32 folder. Now, i want to minimize my CPU usage. What should i do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Press `Windows key + R` and type `devmgmt.msc` and look for errors, broken devices, unknown devices, etc. and fix/update where necessary.

`ntoskrnl.exe` is your kernel.
Increased CPU usage of this is often caused by driver-related issues.